How to do shallow snaphsot testing in React 18
So the story is the following:
I have a React component. I want to unit test the rendering. Previously I've used shallow rendering from enzyme and snapshot testing for this purhose. Let me elaborate my preferences to avoid repeating myself later.
Why snapshots?
Because one "matchSnapshot" test covers all the html checks with single line of code. Snapshot changes are later commited to code review and reviewed by team. I like it much more than 20+ tests that check "<a> is on a page" "<a> href is this one" "button is on the page" "button text is "submit" and dozens of similar. Tests like this are bloating the codebase. The only test worse is expect(func).toBeDefined()
Why shallow?
Because this is a unit test. If you do the full snapshot, the file will get incredibly big, hard to review, and cause false failures when the internal implementation changes. If dev runs the test and sees 200+ rows in snapshot updated, usually that snapshot gets approved without examination.
I use react-testing-library with full render for everything else but simple html structure checks. I use it to test user behavior, I use it to test complex interactions and responses.  Its perferct for it.
Unfortunately, with enzyme latest relase beeing 5 years old, I must write very verbose mocks to achieve clean tiny snapshots.
vi.mock('@mui/joy/Button', () => ({
    default: ({ children, ...rest }: React.PropsWithChildren) => <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
}))

vi.mock('@mui/joy/CardCover', () => ({
    default: ({ children, ...rest }: React.PropsWithChildren) => <div {...rest}>{children}</div>
}))

//And 9 more for every mui component used

Is there a better way? A way to spend less time on mocking dependencies but still receive clean snapshots?
